# How to run sample Scala vertx project

Tags: scala, vert.x

I started new project using sbt new vert-x3/vertx-scala.g8 command. In sbt console entered following command :
vertx.deployVerticle(nameForVerticle[HttpVerticle])

The following error is reported:

```
vertx.deployVerticle(nameForVerticle[HttpVerticle])
<console>:12: error: not found: value vertx
   vertx.deployVerticle(nameForVerticle[HttpVerticle])
   ^
<console>:12: error: not found: value nameForVerticle
   vertx.deployVerticle(nameForVerticle[HttpVerticle])
                        ^
<console>:12: error: not found: type HttpVerticle
```

Followed the steps specified on this page: https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-sbt-starter

How to get sample project running?

Answer (score 0):

I think g8 template is a little bit broken. I made it work using below tricks:

1. Use latest SBT version **1.2.8** in file: project/build.properties
2. When you run console, import HttpVerticle class manually. In my case, I have **test.HttpVerticle** as class name. Because I used package name as 'test', when I was running SBT new command to initialise the project

   scala> `import test.HttpVerticle`
   scala> `vertx.deployVerticle(nameForVerticle[HttpVerticle])`

// This stuff is going to printed in a second:

```
scala> Thread Thread[vert.x-eventloop-thread-0,5,run-main-group-0] has been blocked for 2377 ms, time limit is 2000 
Thread Thread[vert.x-eventloop-thread-0,5,run-main-group-0] has been blocked for 3378 ms, time limit is 2000 
Thread Thread[vert.x-eventloop-thread-0,5,run-main-group-0] has been blocked for 4384 ms, time limit is 2000
```

And then try to trigger the server:

```
curl http://localhost:8666/hello
```

It should reply with "world".

Again, as for class name. If you didn't use any package name when running sbt new initialisation process, then try just import class like this: `import HttpVerticle`

Comment: I cannot get SBT version 1.2.8. I have posted question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54848489/how-to-change-sbt-version-for-project